# GatewayChallengeHandler: handleChallenge() not being called after upgrading to MobileFirst v.8.0

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-mobilefirst

We have a production iOS app that currently runs under MFP 7.0.  I am upgrading it to MFP 8.0.

In the existing version, we extend ChallengeHander as ISAMChallengeHandler to handle ISAM gateway login requests.  For v8.0, I changed ISAMChallengeHandler to extend GatewayChallengeHandler. This involved changing isCustomResponse() to canHandleResponse() and removing a call to submitFailure().

The new version isn't working as expected.  When I call an adapter using WLClient.getInstance().invokeProcedure(...), the gateway returns the login screen, and ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse() is properly called and is returning true.  But handleChallenge() never gets called.

Instead it appears that the HTTP request to the adapter is tried again, resulting in another call to canHandleResponse().  This happens 7 times in a row without any attempt to call handleChallenge().  Then an error from WLResourceRequest occurs, and the WLDelegate gets the onFailure() callback.

What can be causing this behavior? The application's logic has not changed from the 7.0 version.   Is invokeProcedure() not supported anymore?  I get Xcode deprecation warnings on wlConnectWithDelegate() and  WLProcedureInvocationData(), but not invokeProcedure() (which doesn't make sense).

The HTTP retries always happen seven times. Below are the log entries from the app showing this. I've removed the "Response Content" lines for readablility. LoginManager is the class that calls invokeProcedure() using LoginListener as the WLDelegate.

```
2017-02-07 20:41:41.613 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <AppDelegate> App starting: Optional("1.0") Optional("309.2")
2017-02-07 20:41:41.619 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <AppDelegate> deviceDate (UTC): 2017-02-08 02:41:41 +0000
2017-02-07 20:41:41.620 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <AppDelegate> deviceDate (localtime): Feb 7, 2017, 8:41:41 PM
2017-02-07 20:41:41.669 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <LoginManager.connectAndLogin>
2017-02-07 20:41:42.386 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> returning FALSE
2017-02-07 20:41:43.595 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> returning FALSE
2017-02-07 20:41:43.595 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ConnectListener.onSuccess> connectionSuccess
2017-02-07 20:41:43.596 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <LoginManager.connectionSuccess>
2017-02-07 20:41:43.599 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <LoginManager.authenticate> Invoking Worker/getWorker
2017-02-07 20:41:44.469 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> Found "/pkmslogin.form"
2017-02-07 20:41:44.470 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> returning TRUE
2017-02-07 20:41:44.584 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> Found "/pkmslogin.form"
2017-02-07 20:41:44.585 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> returning TRUE
2017-02-07 20:41:44.682 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> Found "/pkmslogin.form"
2017-02-07 20:41:44.682 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> returning TRUE
2017-02-07 20:41:44.782 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> Found "/pkmslogin.form"
2017-02-07 20:41:44.782 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> returning TRUE
2017-02-07 20:41:44.878 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> Found "/pkmslogin.form"
2017-02-07 20:41:44.878 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> returning TRUE
2017-02-07 20:41:44.973 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> Found "/pkmslogin.form"
2017-02-07 20:41:44.974 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> returning TRUE
2017-02-07 20:41:45.075 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> Found "/pkmslogin.form"
2017-02-07 20:41:45.076 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> returning TRUE
2017-02-07 20:41:45.076 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] [ERROR] [WORKLIGHT] -[WLResourceRequest requestFailed:error:] in WLResourceRequest.m:695 :: WL_OAUTH
2017-02-07 20:41:45.094 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <LoginListener.onFailure> Cannot retrieve a valid authorization header for header. Check resource and authorization server configuration.
2017-02-07 20:41:45.095 sitecompliance[50592:4035152] <LoginViewController.loginFailure> System error.
```

Here is the beginning of ISAMChallenger handler showing the canHandleResponse() and handleChallenge() methods:

```
class ISAMChallengeHandler: GatewayChallengeHandler
{
    let baseURL: String!

    override init(){
        baseURL = "\(getBaseURL()!)"
        super.init(gatewayName: "HeaderAuthRealm")
    }

    override func canHandleResponse(response: WLResponse!) -> Bool
    {
        if response != nil {
            if response.responseText != nil {
                if response.responseText.rangeOfString("PKMS Administration: Expired Password") != nil {
                    MQALogger.log("<ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> Found \"PKMS Administration: Expired Password\"")
                    MQALogger.log("<ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> returning TRUE")
                    return true
                }
                if response.responseText.rangeOfString("/pkmslogin.form") != nil {
                    MQALogger.log("<ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> Found \"/pkmslogin.form\"")
                    MQALogger.log("<ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> returning TRUE")
                    return true
                }

            }
        }
        MQALogger.log("<ISAMChallengeHandler.canHandleResponse> returning FALSE")
        return false
    }

    override func handleChallenge(response: WLResponse!)
    {
        //HPDIA0200W Authentication failed. You have used an invalid user name, password or client certificate.
        let failedLogin = response.responseText.rangeOfString("HPDIA0200W") != nil
        let passwordExpired = response.responseText.rangeOfString("PKMS Administration: Expired Password") != nil
        let worker = Worker.getWorker()

        if worker.authDataSet && !failedLogin && !passwordExpired
        {
            MQALogger.log("<ISAMChallengeHandler.handleChallenge> Sending stored login data to ISAM")
            submitISAMAuthData()
        }
        else
        {
            MQALogger.log("<ISAMChallengeHandler.handleChallenge> A login screen form should appear")
            if failedLogin {
                needCredentials("Please check your credentials.")
            } else if passwordExpired {
                worker.password = nil
                saveObjects()
                notify("Password expired",
                    myMessage: "Change on ServiceArizona secure gateway, then sign into app again.", vc: nil)
                    { self.showLoginView() }
            } else {
                needCredentials(nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the ISAM integration tutorial for v8.0 (including samples for Android and iOS? See here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/product-integration/8.0/isam-integration/

Comment: Our existing 7.0 design is similar to that tutorial example except we are not using ltpa cookies.  Are they required in 8.0? In any case, the problem is occurring on login (before ltpa would be involved).   The core issue is that our canHandleResponse() implementation is returning TRUE, but handleChallenge() is never called.  That logic is in the API.  Could it be a bug?

Comment: Maybe. I suggest to open a PMR to take that further...

Comment: Okay.  By the way, the iOS sample app link on that tutorial page returns a 404.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. Will be live soon. Meanwhile you can find it here: https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/ISAMSwift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our architecture has a proxy server in front both the ISAM/WebSeal server and the MFP server.  The proxy directs each MFP request to one or the other depending on whether or not it needs to be authorized by WebSeal.  This was working in MFP 7 but not MFP 8.

We discovered that if we set up *all* MFP traffic to go through the ISAM, then the GatewayChallengeHandler worked properly, but this wasn't a valid solution for our environment.

A little proxy log investigation found up that the MFP 8 API sends a "pre-auth" HTTP request to the server after `canHandleResponse()` returns but before `handleChallenge()` is called.  This wasn't clear from the docs or the API logging. The proxy was sending that pre-auth request directly to the MFP server (not the ISAM).

When we added a proxy rule to send all pre-auth requests (`/mfp/api/preauth/*`) to ISAM, the GatewayChallengeHandler problem was fixed, and we could keep our non-secured MFP requests going directly to the MFP server.

Answer (score 1):

The design has been changed in 8.0 and the LTPA is the way to go at the moment for authenticating mobile first resources via ISAM. The class used for handling the custom challenges is `GatewayChallengeHandler()` which is correctly used in your sample.

The function to capture the challenges sent from network should be processed using `canHandle()`. I see, in your sample, `canHandleResponse()` is being used. I guess that may be the reason that `handleChallenge()` is not getting called in your code.

Please check the new link attached in the comment above for the sample code.